# Use of "as well, " or "as well as"

Tags: as

In the following phrases, are the use of the **"as well"** according to the grammar for academic issues? Or as missing another **"as"**, for example **"as well as"**.

> In the situation A the results are good.  For the B situation **as well,**
>   the modelled results are similar to the field data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of **as well** here is correct.

The usage of **as well as** would have transformed the sentence as follows:

> In situation A **as well as** in situation B, the modelled results are similar to the field data.